# MariaDB how to discover the time when a line was inserted

Tags: mariadb

I have a legacy table inside MariaDB where there is no date column, so we can not see when in which day or time one register was inserted or updated.

Is there any MariaDB SQL command that can show the day and time that a register was created or updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no SQL command.

You can check when a table was created/updated or modified by using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` but not when a row was modified (for that you usually have the `TIMESTAMP`column in a table which will automatically updated).

A non SQL way would be (provided that the binary log has been activated) to use the mariadb-binlog/mysqlbinlog utility for analyzing the binary log. e.g.

```
# at 662
#190927  8:45:06 server id 1  end_log_pos 754 CRC32 0xfdd6a613  Query   thread_id=10    exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1569566706/*!*/;
insert into t1 values (1)
```

The SQL command `SHOW BINLOG EVENTS` can't be used, since it doesn't display timestamps.

Comment: InnoDB tables tend not to update the "modified" column in `TABLES`.  (At least that was the case in older versions.)

Comment: It is available since 10.2.2